# How to make sure that click event will fire only after http call come back using RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I try to play with rxjs schedualer.
Is it possible to make sure that click event callback will be triggered only after http call come back using scheduler?
I tried some code but the click is always triggered before.
Is it possible to achieve only using scheduler?
[image]

Relevant code from image:

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  fromEvent(this.btnn.nativeElement, 'click')
    .pipe(
      observeOn(asyncScheduler)
    )
  .subscribe(res => console.log('click'));

  this.http.get('some-url')
    .pipe(
      observeOn(asapScheduler), 
      delay(3000)
    )
  .subscribe(res => console.log('response'));
}
```

Comment: share code as text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the click events to only be handled after the http call comes back (finishes) you can concat them together:

```
this.http.get().pipe(
  tap(res => console.log('http res', res)),
  ignoreElements(), 
  concatWith(
    fromEvent(this.btn...., 'click')
  )
)
.subscribe(_ => console.log('click');
```

But this makes them dependant on each other, your click events will never be handled if the http response somehow does not come back. That is a functionality decision to make

https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatWith
https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/ignoreElements

Comment: That’s great thanks, but I try to learn about schedualers and I wondering if it’s possible to do so using schedualer only?

Comment: @AlexKoretzki trying to manipulate order of observables using the scheduler is a big smell of behaviour / responsibilities being in the wrong place. For a learning experience you can play with it but keep that in mind. Don't know if it will work as you want it to

Comment: Yes it’s only for learning purpose. I wonder how to do it..